# How do I apply conditional formatting using SharePoint Designer 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2013, formatting

I'm attempting to apply Conditional Formatting to a list view web part via SharePoint Designer 2013, and I can't seem to find the option to do so.

I've a horrible feeling I'm just being daft, but here's what I've done so far:

- Created a new page (I've tried both web part and wiki)
- Added a list "App part" and saved the page
- Checked-out and opened the page via Designer
- Clicked the "Edit file" option
- Selected the XsltListViewWebPart tag

So far I can't find any options to add it. If I open the Conditional Formatting pane via the View menu it tells me the following:

> To use conditional formatting, select an HTML tag, data value, or
>   range of text, and then click Create to specify formatting options.

I've tried selecting the web part tags in all manner of combinations with no luck. In previous version I would have simply selected the previewed data rows in the now-absent Preview pane.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this isn't currently possible without customising the list's XSL directly:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomization/thread/1e4ffdeb-8de2-4da6-905a-581e26c7875c

> as I understood, this option is not available "native" in SPD 2013.
>   Theres is no "design-View" anymore....
>
> When you want to customize the list you have to create manually an
>   xsl-template for this list.
>
> Also me hope to get some helpful answers here how to customize lists,
>   esp. External BCS-Lists...
>
> Me I'm not deep in the topic of xsl-Style and formatting and I enyod
>   to this in SPD2010.